# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory Error . Please Check my Dependecies and find the error

Tags: android

My Manifest File
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmT6v.jpg
How can I solve this error as it says "Manifest merger failed :

> Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-37:19 to override."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.piyushgarg.socialmedia">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".login"/>
        <activity android:name=".register"/>
        <activity android:name=".setup"/>
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    </application>

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->

</manifest>
```

MY GRADLE FILE DEPENDENCIES

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
}
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: see duplicate question with answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803943/manifest-merger-failed-after-import-a-module/56853863#56853863

Answer (score 0):

try adding name in your manifest under application tag

```
<application
android:name=".YourApplicationClass"
```

application class is  a `class` extending `Application`